# Avoid double-calling function in string assignment in ctor initializer list

Tags: c++, ctor-initializer

In the following code example, I want to initialize `std::string A::str_` in `A`'s initializer list with either the return value from a function (that may return `NULL`), or a `const char*`. But I don't like the fact that `Func()` is called twice.

```
#include <iostream>

const char* Func()
{
  char* p = NULL;
  // Assign p: may be NULL or non-NULL
  return p;
}

class A
{
public:
  A() : str_( Func() ? Func() : "NULL" ) {}

  std::string str_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  A a;
  std::cout << a.str_ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
A() : str_( ( const char*& tmp = Func() ) ? tmp : "NULL" ) {}
```

But using temporary variables - even references, to lengthen their lifespan - in this manner seems illegal (per my current understanding).

Is there C++03 syntax that would allow for the initialization of `A::str_` in the initializer list, calling `Func()` only once, and without the use of global/static variables? If there is a solution that uses temporary variables, I would like to learn its syntax.

Comment: You could wrap that in a (private static) helper function.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I like that idea; thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in C++11, use delegate constructor

```
class A
{
private:
    A(const char* s) str_(s ? s : "NULL") {}
public:
  A() : A(Func()) {}

  std::string str_;
};
```

In c++03, create a function helper

```
class A
{
private:
    static const char* FuncNotNull() { const char* s = Func(); return s ? s : "NULL"); }
public:
  A() : str_(FuncNotNull()) {}

  std::string str_;
};
```

Comment: I didn't know about delegate ctors: I was still under the old thinking that ctors cannot call other ctors. Thank you.

Comment: Not really relevant, but g++ has a non-standard extension `a ?: b` which means `a ? a : b` but only evaluating `a` once ; there's been a few times that this would have saved some fluffing around with syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution in which a lambda expression is "abused":

```
A() : str_( ([]()->const char*{ const char* p=Func(); return (p ? p : "NULL"); })() ) {}
```

I actually voted for Jarod's answer.
But I find the lambda thing that ugly that I wanted to show it as well :-)